# Date Picker Date Returns Null If date is Greater than MM/10/YYYY

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I using Jquery DatePicker and Collecting the Values From text box and Passing to C# Controller The Problem is When i select Date below 10th it is going to controller Properly But If date is more Than 10(05/21/2015) it is Giving null value So i Placed Break point In browser And checked for values there it is getting correctly

```
 <!--/PAGE -->
<!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<!-- JQUERY -->
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- JQUERY UI-->
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
<script src="~/Content/bootstrap-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- COOKIE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jQuery-Cookie/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<!-- CUSTOM SCRIPT -->   
<script src="~/Content/js/Advertisement.js"></script>

<script>
    // A $( document ).ready() block.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#strtdate,#enddate").datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });

    });
</script>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 form_field">
 <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
 <input type="text" id="strtdate" class="form-control">
 </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Problem might be in the date format. Datepicker value is passed in `mm/dd/yyyy`. Pass it as `dd/mm/yyyy/` and Check your model.

Comment: Thank you @ShaunakD Changed Format It Works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option

```
format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

is incorrect. Use **[dateFormat](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)**

```
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
```

The problem why *04/10/2015* works,but *04/21/2015* does not is because the Date is passed to the controller as **dd/mm/yy** format. And `mm(month)=21` is invalid.